# How do I search for files in unique folders on my network drive using two keywords, and return date modified information to my spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have asked this question differently, but here was the answer to find files in a single folder on a networked drive.

```
Sub GetFilesDetails()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arrKeys, arrDate, i As Long, fileName As String
  Dim folderPath As String, lastModifDate As Date, lastDate As Date
  Const key2 As String = "Proof"
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary worksheet
  lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  
  arrKeys = sh.Range("B4:B" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
  arrDate = sh.Range("G4:G" & lastR).Value2
 
  folderPath = "C:/the necessary folder path" 'Use here your real Folder Path!!!
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrKeys)
        If arrKeys(i, 1) <> "" Then
            fileName = Dir(folderPath & "\" & "*" & arrKeys(i, 1) & "*" & key2 & "*.xlsx")
            lastDate = 0
            Do While fileName <> ""
                lastModifDate = CDate(Int(FileDateTime(folderPath & "\" & fileName)))
                If lastModifDate > lastDate Then lastDate = lastModifDate
                fileName = Dir
            Loop
            If lastModifDate <> 0 Then arrDate(i, 1) = lastModifDate: lastModifDate = 0
        End If
  Next i
  
  With sh.Range("G4").Resize(UBound(arrDate), 1)
        .Value2 = arrDate
        .NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy"
  End With
End Sub
```

I need help to find multiple files in multiple unique folders on my network drive and return a date modified to my spreadsheet.

Comment: Can the searched file name exist in any folder/subfolder? Or a pattern of subfolder/file name should be defined, as I understood from your previous question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next approach. Not tested, but it should be working, I think. Take care to place a ending backslash ("") in the "drivePath" main folder. It assumes that the files to be processed for a specific pair of the two keys should be found in a folder following the next pattern: main_folder\unknown_folder_Name"*" & numeric_key & "*"\PROOF"*" & numeric_key & "*" & AlphaNumeric_Key & "*.pdf"

```
Sub GetFilesDetailsAllFolders()
    Const drivePath As String = "S:\", fileExt As String = "*.pdf"
    Const key1 As String = "PROOF"

    Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arrKeys, arrDate, i As Long
    Dim arrF, El, arrFold, strFold As String, boolFound As Boolean
    Dim strGoodFold As String, sFoldCol As New Collection, LastD As Date
    
    Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary worksheet
    lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  
    arrKeys = sh.Range("B4:B" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
    arrDate = sh.Range("G4:G" & lastR).Value2
    
    arrF = AllFiles(drivePath, fileExt, True) 'build an array of all files having fileExt extension (from all folders and subfolders)!
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrKeys)
        If arrKeys(i, 1) <> "" Then
            For Each El In arrF
                If (strGoodFold <> "") And (left(El, InStrRev(El, "\")) <> strGoodFold) Then
                    strGoodFold = "": Exit For 'if iteration passed the appropriate (unique) subfolder...
                End If
                arrFold = Split(Replace(El, drivePath, ""), "\")
                
                If UBound(arrFold) = 3 Then 'process only files full name having 3 subfolders (except drivePath):
                    If arrFold(1) Like "*" & arrKeys(i, 1) & "*" And _
                                arrFold(2) Like key1 And arrFold(3) Like _
                                "*" & arrKeys(i, 1) & "*" & key1 & fileExt Then
                        boolFound = True: strGoodFold = left(El, InStrRev(El, "\")) 'the path to exit the code if not the same folder
                        sFoldCol.Add El          'add the full name in the collection
                    End If
                End If
            Next El
            
            If boolFound Then     'sFoldCol has been loaded with at least one file full path string
                boolFound = False 'reitialize the boolean variable to cnnfirm collection loading
                arrDate(i, 1) = LastModif(sFoldCol): Set sFoldCol = Nothing 'clear the collection
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    'drop the processec array content and format the range as Date:
    With sh.Range("G4").Resize(UBound(arrDate), 1)
        .Value2 = arrDate
        .NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy"
    End With
End Sub
```

It needs the function to return all files full name, from all folders and subfolders of the main one:

```
Private Function AllFiles(strFold As String, Optional strExt As String = "*.*", Optional boolSubfolders = False) As Variant
    Dim arrFiles, i As Long, lastName As String, lngNb As Long, arrN, El
    'return all files name in an array:
    If boolSubfolders Then 'subfolders included:
        arrFiles = filter(Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").Exec("cmd /c dir """ & strFold & strExt & """ /b/s").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), "\")
    Else                         'without subfolders:
        arrFiles = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").Exec("cmd /c dir """ & strFold & strExt & """ /b").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
        arrFiles = Split(strFold & Join(arrFiles, "|" & strFold), "|")                                'add the folder path to the file names
        arrFiles(UBound(arrFiles)) = "@@##": arrFiles = filter(arrFiles, "@@##", False) 'remove the last (empty) array element
    End If

    AllFiles = arrFiles
End Function
```

And another one to return the last modified date, for the specific files:

```
Function LastModif(col As Collection) As Date
   Dim lastModifDate As Date, lastDate As Date, El
   For Each El In col
        lastModifDate = CDate(Int(FileDateTime(El)))
        If lastModifDate > lastDate Then lastDate = lastModifDate
   Next El
  
   If lastModifDate <> 0 Then LastModif = lastModifDate
End Function
```

Since not tested and I must leave my office now, it may have problems. Or not... I am sure that the logic behind it is OK, but if I missed something, please do not hesitate to explain what problem, what error and on what code line. If the above assumption is not a correct one, please state which to be the basis.

I will be able to see your comment after some hours, when I will be at home...

Comment: I think this works! It's hard to say for sure due to the time it takes to run. Excel turns to "Not Responding" Fast haha. The root is 6TB so i'm not sure if it's size is what is causing the code to run slowly. I have had dates returned correctly though, so i'm going to let it run for a while and see what happens!

Comment: @Jakebnda 6TB? This is huge! **You should mention that**... The above code **firstly** extracts **all pdf files from all existing folders and subfolders** and place them in an array which is processed further. I am surprised that Excel has not been crushing... I think, not only a working code should be the target. It should be (somehow) efficient for such a huge environment. We should find a way to limit somehow the subfolders level limit at 3. Unfortunately there is not such a standard command in the way I used the function.

Comment: @Jakebnda Now, if I remember well, you were talking about some strings containing "school" word in the first subfolder level. Is this correct? If not only "school" is it a big list of possible such strings?

Comment: Comparatively, School would be a small list of possibilities. I have let the cmd run and it is not getting all of the dates. I think maybe some of the proofs are in the "...\WO51331_*\" Folder while some are in a "\PROOF\" Folder instead of "\PROOFS\"

Comment: @Jakebnda Since `key1` is "PROOF" between the wildcards, "PROOFS" will also be processed. I hope, you used the code as it is. If you changed "PROOF" to "PROOFS", "PROOF" is escaped...  I am not sure that you can accurately check if all of the dates has been processed. I can adapt the code to also return (for each pair of keys) the full name of processed files. If you are sure that there are such files not being processed, please copy here their full names to analize against the processing rules. Maybe the folders keeping the files to be processed are not unique and only the first is processed.

Comment: Here are some of the files that were not found. (Also it takes about 30 min to run haha) "S:\Mastertag\WO53364_PO2591.2592 & 2593_WALTERS CARDS\WO53364_PROOF1.pdf"  "S:\True North Energy\WO53312 INTERCHANEABLE PRICE SIGN\WO53312_PROOF1.pdf"  "S:\Biggby Coffee\2022\WO53218_BIGGBY COFFEE_WINDOW GRAPHICS_CHEAT SHEET DECALS\PROOFS\WO53218_PROOF1.pdf"

Comment: So it looks like the ones without the subfolder "PROOFS" and one that has an extra subfolder after the company name of "...\2022\" One subfolder too short, and one subfolder too long...

Comment: All the examples you collected **do not respect the pattern you asked for**... First two miss subfolder "PROOF(S)" and the last one has the "PROOFS" folder of the fifth level. Without consistency in the data range you try processing, or using a different evaluation algorithm, your problem cannot be solved, I am afraid...

Comment: I appreciate your help. I am working with a company system where multiple people are inputing file and folder names so the difficulty is in a standardized filing system. I will have to manually go through and change files and folders to this algorithm and implement a standard within the company. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Jakebnda Good idea! I suppose that the huge drive is not used only for solving the above issue. If so, I would suggest you to do it in a different way and **doing manually only a list of the first folders** (except the drive letter), which **automatically** to be copied **in a new created folder**, relevantly named to keep all folders, subfolders and file of this project. This will increase the above code speed considerably. It will also make **much faster** if that **first folder** name will be recorded in the Excel list keeping the keys.

Comment: @Jakebnda Having the first folder per numeric key, I can change the solution to use `Dir()`, firstly to 'build' the path, of each folder and finally the files to be processed... It will be very fast and good to be used only if reducing the huge amount of folders and subfolders to be processed, in order to return the first array...

Comment: The spreadsheet has the company name on it... Maybe 3 Keys would allow the use of Dir()? Key1 = Company Name (A4:A)  Key2 = WO# (B4:B) Key3 = "PROOF"   That would remove the need to create an array for the whole drive. For example: S:\Key1\Key2\PROOF(S)\File.pdf)  (S:\ChurchA\WO_8675309\PROOF\WO_8675309.pdf)

Comment: What does "company name" mean? The exact string of the first subfolder? If not, what? a string hundred percent sure to be content in the first subfolder name? Even so, is there a **unique such subfolder name** per each company?

Comment: Most (95%) are the exact string. Few(5%) are contained in the subfolder name. This would save me a lot of hours renaming folders. Yes, There is a unique subfolder name for each company as well.